# Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\xA4\x96<b…' for column 'body' at row 1

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, unicode, utf8mb4

I've set the column type to utf8mb4 and the collation to utf8mb4_bin. The table defaults are also utf8mb4 and utf8mb4_bin.

When I use SequelPro to add the emoji "" to the database manually, it works just fine.

However, when I do an INSERT using JDBC, it gives me the Incorrect String Value error.

Here is my connection string:  `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myschema`
I'm using `mysql-connector-java-5.1.32-bin.jar`

What am I doing wrong?

Here is some of the code I'm using:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO table VALUES (?)"
String body = ...;
statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
statement.setString(1, body)
statement.execute();
```

Comment: How can we know what you're doing wrong, when you don't show the code? E.g. are you doing insert using a `Statement` or a `PreparedStatement`? **Edit** the question and show the *relevant* code.

Comment: prepared statement.  I edited the question and added some code.

Comment: Is your connection also `utf8mb4`?

Comment: I've tried different connection strings, but can't get it to work.  jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mySchema?useUnicode=true&character_set_server=utf8mb4 connects to the server but still have the same bug

Comment: when I try "characterEncoding=utf8mb4" it throws an unsupported encoding exception

Comment: figured out i needed to do "characterEncoding=UTF-8"

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  I needed to put `characterEncoding=UTF-8` into the JDBC connection URL.

Read more here:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-charsets.html